# referencing a form field inside of JS does not work

Tags: javascript

**TL DR** named field inside a form is not being recoginzed inside of *JS*.

I've got a form and some javascript. Inside the form there is a field with a `name="adverts"`. For some reason I'm getting an error that...

> adverts.addEventListener is not a function

and now my `function poprequire` does not work. I can get rid of the error by adding 
`let adverts = document.getElementById('adverts');` inside the `addEventListener`, but that does not solve the problem, as the function `poprequire` still does not work.

Any help would be welcome.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="popupform" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" id="popupform">
        <div id="adv-t">Want to recieve adverts?</div><br />
    <label class="mlist">
    <input type="checkbox" name="adverts" id="adverts" value="Yes">
        <span id="adv-c">Yes, naturally.</span>
        <br />
    </label><br />
    <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z][^0-9]{2,25}" name="popupfname" id="popupfname" placeholder="Janez"autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" /><br />
    <span id="pf" class="error pfn" aria-live="polite"></span><br />
    <input type="email" name="popupemail" id="popupemail" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" maxlength="45" placeholder="moj@email.si"/><br />
    <span id="pe" class="error pem" aria-live="polite"></span><br /><br />
    <div id="small">By checking the box, you will recieve emails etc etc.
    </div>  
        <hr style="margin-top: -6px;">
    <button id="allow"">
        <span id="a">Proceed</span>
    </button>
    <button id="deny" onclick="deny()">
        <span id="d">Return</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

```
const popupfname = document.getElementById('popupfname');

const popupemail = document.getElementById('popupemail');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    adverts.addEventListener('input', poprequire);
    popupfname.addEventListener('input', popfn);
    popupemail.addEventListener('input', popem);
});

function poprequire(event){
    if (adverts.checked === true){
        document.getElementById("popupfname").required = true;
        document.getElementById("popupemail").required = true;
            popupfnShowError();
            popupemShowError();
    }else{
        document.getElementById("popupfname").required = false;
        document.getElementById("popupemail").required = false;
        popfn();
        popem(); 
    }
```

Comment: adverts is a type="checkbox" you shuld use change instead of input

Comment: at <button id="allow""> you have a typo

Comment: in this snippet you miss } at the end

Comment: thank you. will change it and see how it goes

Comment: it still says adverts is not a function

Comment: Where is adverts defined? I don't see a const or let or var in here...

Comment: i though the name="adverts" was enough. I also tried it with `let adverts = document.getElementById('adverts');`, which removed the error but the function still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your adverts.addEventListener to something like this..

```
    var adverts = document.querySelector("input[name=adverts]");
    adverts.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            console.log("CHECKED")
        } else {
           console.log("NOT")
    });
}
```